# How to find the position of a digit and use them

Tags: c++, encoding

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    int value,
    cout << "Input your number: " << endl;
   cin >> input;
   const int count = input.length();
   istringstream buffer(input);
   buffer >> value;
   if (count == 4) {
```

My program is suppose to count the length of the number, if it's 4 then encode the digits. Eg. 1234 turns to some other digits. My question is how do I take each individual digit and use them. Eg. take (1+1)/10, or (3+2)/10.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a character in a string using the bracket notation, e.g `input[0]` to get the first character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this another way (to handle input like `0001` or `12ab` correctly):

- read the input to an `int`
- convert it to `std::string` with `std::to_string` (C++ 11)
- check the string's size

and you have a `std::string` of which you can access the digits like `str[0] - '0'` (you get an integer in range [0; 9]).

---

Another option is simply reading into a string and then checking if `std::all_of` characters hold true for `std::isdigit`.